# google drive api Cannot access private property Google_Client::$io

Tags: php, google-api

Good afternoon!
I'm trying to download the file.
My script:

```
function GetFile($service, $fileId) {
    $fileVars = null;
    try {
        $file = $service->files->get($fileId);
        $fileVars = get_object_vars($file);
        $downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
        error_log('Download URL file from Drive: ' . $downloadUrl);
        if ($downloadUrl) {
            $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null); 
            $httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
            error_log(print_r($httpRequest, 1));

            if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
                $content = $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
                $fileVars['content'] = $content?($content):'';
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    } catch (apiServiceException $e) {
        error_log('Error retrieving file from Drive: ' . $e->getMessage());
        throw $e;
    }
    return json_encode($fileVars);
}

$requestedFile = GetFile($service,$data[0]['id']);
```

I deduces that
Fatal error: Cannot access private property Google_Client::$io

Tell me, what is my mistake?
Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
$SignhttpRequest = $client->getAuth()->sign($request);
$httpRequest = $client->getIo()->makeRequest($SignhttpRequest);
```

Comment: even with these commands in succesion, I still get a 401 error. Any idea?   ---------  $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);        $SignhttpRequest = $client->getAuth()->sign($request);         $httpRequest = $client->getIo()->makeRequest($SignhttpRequest);

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$httpRequest = $client->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);`

instead of

`$httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);`

See annotations in google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/Abstract.php for class Google_Auth_Abstract:

> An utility function that first calls $this->auth->sign($request) and then executes makeRequest() on that signed request.

And see [Google's migration guide 'Migrating From 0.6.* to 1.0.0'](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/migration)  sections 'Changes in members accessibility' and 'A new home for authenticatedRequest'.